# PHP BD error line 72

Tags: php

The error is Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::retrieve_all_accounts() in /home/mjcrawle/public_html/cit0215/assignment5/onlinebanking/viewaccounts.php on line 72

I am not getting any html errors so I will leave that out.

My php code  up to the error is:

```
<?php 

require_once('footer_nav/navigation.inc.php'); 
require_once('../websiteconfig.inc.php');
require_once('../class/person_class.php');
require_once('../class/database.class.php');

/*Start Session*/
session_start();

$currentMember =unserialize($_session['currentMember']);

/*DataBase*/
$db = new Database;
$conn = $db->connection;
?>
<td width="16">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="595">
</td>
</tr>

</div>


<h2>Accounts</h2>  


</td>
<table id="accounts" summary="Bank Account Balance Information">
<thread>
    <tr>
        <th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Account Balance</th>
     </tr>
  </thead> 
<tbody>     
<php?
/*Accounts*/
$currentMember->connection = $conn;
```

this is where I get the error line 72:

```
$accounts = $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts();

/* Loop Though Accounts*/
while($account = mysqli_fetch_assoc($account)) {
    /* Retrieve Account Balance*/
$bankaccount = new Bankaccount ($account['BankAccountID']);
$bankaccount->connection = $conn;
$balance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bankaccount->retrieve_current_balance());

 echo '<tr>' . "\n";
 echo "\t" . '<td class="account_number">' . $account['BankAccountID'] . '</td>' . "\n";
 echo "\t" . '<td class="account_balance">$' .   number_format($balance['CurrentBalance'], 2) . '</td>' . "\n";
 echo '</tr>' . "\n";

}

/*Closed DataBase*/ 
mysqli_close($db->connection);

?>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no such method as retrieve_all_accounts()?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using this, in your first portion of code :

```
<php?
/*Accounts*/
$currentMember->connection = $conn;
```

If you really copy-pasted this, you have a problem here : this is not PHP code.

Instead, you should have :

```
<?php
/*Accounts*/
$currentMember->connection = $conn;
```

Note that a PHP opening tag is `<?php` and not `<php?`

Then, your `$currentMember` variable is set this way :

```
$currentMember =unserialize($_session['currentMember']);
```

It seems this makes `$currentMember` just on container, and not an instance of a class that would have a `retrieve_all_accounts()` method.

So, when trying to call that method :

```
$accounts = $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts();
```

You get a Fatal error, because there is no such method in your `$currentMember` object.